# What are the hardware configurations required for opening front and back cameras simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, multi-camera-api

I managed to preview back & front cameras simultaneously, using Camera2 API ([multiple-camera-streams-simultaneously](https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/multiple-camera-streams-simultaneously))

It works pretty well on OnePlus 8 (pro) device BUT didn't work on others such as Samsung Galaxy A32 and OnePlus 7 (pro);
got the error: ERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE, while trying to open the second camera.

How can I know which devices can support it ?
I understand there is HW criteria for that, but what is it ?

Thanks

Comment: I've updated your question title to make sure that you're asking about a specific configuration, instead of asking for devices. asking for devices would probably be off-topic, but asking for configurations would be valid, because you could emulate those. feel free to change it if you disagree

Comment: totally accept it, thanks

Comment: With output type, output size, and hardware level of HAL, you can determine which combinations of streams are valid.

Comment: @WasimAnsari I guess you are talking about the table mentioned here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/multiple-camera-streams-simultaneously
That's the way to know in run time which streams are valid together.
My problem is how to determine which devices has the right hardware to support it, actually, what is the hardware spec to support it ?
I found some threads talking about Snapdragon chipset (>= 801), but eventually after purchasing a Galaxy S10 Lite (snapdragon 855), it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Starting API 30, new methods are added to know availability as well stream configuration for concurrent cameraID that you can use.

https://source.android.com/devices/camera/concurrent-streaming